# Can I make a short visit to Canada on a transit visa?

Tags: visas, canada, transit-visas

I want to visit Canada for one day, going and returning from Rochester, New York the next day. Can I do that on a transit visa?

Comment: Are you a US permanent resident?

Answer (score 4):

[Who needs a transit visa?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/transit-apply-who.asp)

> You need a transit visa if you are from a visa-required country and:
>
> - your international flight stops at a Canadian airport on its way to another country
> - you will be connecting between two international flights at a Canadian airport

It's not ultra short term visitor visa. Don't forget to check [if you need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) an eTA might be enough.